# Is there a tool shaped like a thin-bladed putty knife but with a rubber blade and spongelike surface?

Tags: toilet, cleaning

Sorry if this is a duplicate, thanks in advance!

I am trying to clean up under the rim of my toilet near where the jets are, and I can't reach a finger or rigid brush up there.

There may be a better way, but does anyone know whether there is a tool like the one described in the subject line above? I am looking for something that I could reach through the narrow slit between the rim and wall of the toilet, then scrape across the surface.

Thank you!

Comment: There are kitchen spatulas that are flexible.  If you can't find one the right size, you could cut one down to size.  There are also plastic putty knives.  Or, wrap a thin scouring pad over a putty knife.

Comment: It sounds like a flexible brush like a test tube cleaner might work.

Comment: Another trick if you have hard water deposits:  pour vinegar straight down the tank overflow tube and then wait a few hours. Next, use the test tube brush @MatthewGauthier mentions on the rim holes.

Comment: once you use a steam cleaner, you won't ever consider another method of cleaning disgusting soiled crannys in non-porous surfaces; it blasts the gunk right out without elbow grease or precision movements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a disposable [foam paint brush](https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/51013621)

[image: foam brush]

> Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources

Comment: Thanks to bib for the answer as well as fixer1234, Matthew Gauthier and Tyson 12 for their comments (which I consider just as good)!